# How to prove that a function is bijective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I just began learning about mathematical proofs (the questions I have in homework are mainly about proving bijections between sets) and I found this subject extremely puzzling and confusing and it seems like I can't understand this damn subject...

I understand that if you show that if $f(a)=f(b)$, then $a=b$ and the function is injective. So if I have a function from set $A$ (which is the set of odd natural numbers (without zero)) to set $B$ (even natural numbers (without zero)) $f(a)=a+1$ then you show that it is injective by saying that $a=b$ if $f(a)=f(b)$ because we can take $f(a)=f(b) = a+1=b+1$ and remove $1$ from both sides and turn it to $a=b$. This is a "proof" that the function is injective? Why? Because I could use some operations to turn $a+1=b+1$ to $a=b$?. And how do you prove that a function is surjective?

Comment: It proves the function is injective because you have shown that if f(a)=f(b), you must have a=b. This is the definition of injectivity

Comment: One way to show your function is surjective is to fix an element $x$ in your codomain, and then demonstrate that there is an element $a$ in your domain (in this case, $a=x-1$) such that $f(a)=x$.

Comment: Both of these comments really just restate what it is you want to prove -- but that's the most one can say in general; how to _achieve_ that goal depends _completely_ on what you already know about the function. How is it defined? Which assumptions about it do you have? And so forth. In the simple case of $x+1$, what you need drops directly out of the definitions, but that is sort of an atypical task. Its purpose is to help you familiarize yourself with _what the definitions mean_ before you go on to cases where you need to apply ingenuity to see that the definition is actually satisfied.

Comment: @Eleanor  Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Yes that a correct proof for injectivity.

For sujectivity we need to prove that for every $n$ even exists $a$ odd such that $f(a)=a+1=n$ which is true.

Therefore $f$ is injective and surjective and thus invertible.

Comment: I think OP's function is from odd natural numbers to even natural numbers (excluding 0)

Comment: @AirConditioner ok thanks! I fix